# Delete rows from the table, keeping the most recent ones

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have an Oracle table of data which has duplicate unique IDs but different dates.

I want to delete all the information out the table where the data is not the latest date so if for example the circuit_id has 70 inputs all different dates I want to ONLY KEEP ONE WHICH IS CLOSEST TO TODAYS DATE.

example

```
select circuit_id, date 
from table_name

circuit_id|date
ABCD123 | 22/04/2018
ABCD123 | 10/10/2018
EFGH321 | 20/01/2018
EFGH321 | 08/10/2018
```

I'm looking to build a query where it will delete all the duplicates, leave the 1 input where the date is closest to today's date then delete the rest so the output will be like so.

```
circuit_id | date
ABCD123 | 10/10/2018
EFGH321 | 08/10/2018
```

Comment: This is badly worded and as a result it is difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: im using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select circuit_id, "DATE" 
from (
  select circuit_id, "DATE", 
         row_number() over (partition by circuit_id 
                            order by abs(sysdate - "DATE")) as rn
  from table_name
)
where rn > 1
```

returns all but the "closest" dates - so essentially all cicruit_id/"DATE" combinations that you want to remove.

The above query can be used as the input for an IN operator to a DELETE statement:

```
delete from table_name
where (circuit_id, "DATE") in (
                            select circuit_id, "DATE" 
                            from (
                              select circuit_id, "DATE", 
                                     row_number() over (partition by circuit_id 
                                                        order by abs(sysdate - "DATE")) as rn
                              from table_name
                            )
                            where rn > 1);
```

Comment: this is exaclty what i was after thank you for taking the time to give me this solution

Answer (score -1):

just write

```
delete * from tableName where date="Date"
```

Comment: the table has over 20,000 rows i cant do this for each date i want to delete